# Orders not showing up

Tags: expresso-store

Good morning,

i have a slight problem on a project i'm developing. Using EE2.9.2 and Store 2.5.0.

I have my templating setup for my products, cart, confirmation page. Currently using the MANUAL payment gateway since we're still in development.

When I complete an order everything works on the frontend. I receive de default confirmation email since i haven't changed that yet.

In de backend however I do see my customers appear but i DON'T see the orders appear. The order list is completely empty but the database does show the corresponding entries made by test purchased.

Perhaps an error in 2.5.0?

With kind regard,
Bas van Ginkel

Comment: I have a similar issue to this. Everything is set up properly. I have recently moved from an Apache server to an Nginx server. When an order come in, exp_store_orders is recording the order as it should. However the 'order_status' and 'order_completed_date' are not being updated on a successful purchase. Nor is the cart being emptied. Any idea where I need to start looking to get this working? Store: 1.6.5
EE: 2.5.2 I know these are a little old, but neither I or the client are prepared to pay for updates. This was working on Apache and in theory should be on Nginx. PHP version has only bumped

Answer (score 0):

Store by default shows orders with a Order Status of New and a Payment Status of Paid. Orders taken with the Manual Gateway are not marked as Paid by default so you will want to choose Any or Unpaid from the status dropdown.